# How can I find LDAP lookup string for the user?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, pgbouncer

I want to configure pgBouncer with LDAP and the documentation[1] says we need
 to

> Create the users.txt PgBouncer authentication file. The first field is the user name and the second is the LDAP or Active Directory lookup string for the user

Context of users.txt example

`"gpdbuser1" "ldap://10.0.0.11:10389/uid=gpdbuser1,ou=users,ou=system"`

My question is, How do I find the lookup string for a user?

I found in active directory that I can see my user at following location

`CN=x760770,OU=People,OU=eProfile,DC=hello,DC=hi,DC=yahoo,DC=com`

Can I say the ldap look up string is above? and I can write below in user.txt file

`"gpdbuser1" "ldap://10.0.0.11:10389/CN=x760770,OU=People,OU=eProfile,DC=hello,DC=hi,DC=yahoo,DC=com"`

[1] 
https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/570/admin_guide/access_db/topics/pgbouncer.html#topic_m2h_5dj_5s

Comment: Perhaps you should have a look at the admin guide yourself.  The lookup string for AD looks quite different from the OpenLDAP one you've copied.

Comment: I might be wrong by saying that we have active directory. It can be open LDAP.

Comment: A first step would be to make sure which one it is.